# Should I use `readinto` method of python file or not?

Tags: python, file, numpy, python-2.x, fromfile

I've recently meet the `readinto` method of `file` object (in Python 2.7), it is similar to `fread` in C. It seems to be convenient and powerful in some case. I plan to use it to read several files into one pre-allocated numpy array **without data copied**.

e.g.

```
a = np.empty(N)
b = memoryview(a)
fp1.readinto(b[0:100])
fp2.readinto(b[100:200])
```

and

```
fp1.readinto(b[0:100])
fp1.seek(400, 1)
fp1.readinto(b[100:200])
```

I've used `Cython` and `fread` to do this before I met `readinto`. So I'm very happy to know a pure python solution.

However its document string says,

```
file.readinto?
Type:        method_descriptor
String form: <method 'readinto' of 'file' objects>
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:   readinto() -> Undocumented.  Don't use this; it may go away.
```

**Don't use this**? What happend?

So I'm confused, should I use `readinto` or not? It may cause any unwanted problem?

Is there any alternative implementation for the code above without `readinto` but also **avoid data copy**? (To avoid copy means `np.concatenate` or `np.stack` is not a good choice.)

Any sugguestion is welcome!  Thank you.

-------upate-------

It seems that I can use `io.FileIO` in standard library instead of the build-in function `open`. It looks OK so I've post it as an answer.

Any comment or other solution is still welcome!

-------upate-------

If you meet the same problem, you may want to have a look at the comments below by
Andrea Corbellini and Padraic Cunningham.

Comment: Might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791780/readinto-replacement

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Just typing `file.readinto?` in IPython, this is equivalent to `help(file.readinto)` in the standard python shell.  I've checked other `file` methods as you said, but only `readinto` shows this message.

Comment: Do you maybe want  memmap?http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: For the reference, the "it may go away" message has been there since 2001: https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/646e24728852

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, `memmap` is great and works well in many cases. But if I want to read data from several file or from several discontinuous part of one file into an array, it seems impossible for `memmap`? Ah, wait,  creating a `memmap` won't read the data into memory, until I use it, right? So I can do it like this `a[0:100]=mmap1[some_slice]; a[100:200]=mmap2[some_slice]` and also avoid data copy.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think that's a good alternative solution. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thank you for the infomation. So it seems people finally accept it in the `io` module :)

Comment: @SyrtisMajor, yes exactly, it does not read the whole file into memory but I think you do need a block of free contiguous memory big enough for the file object. Python also has it's own builtin mmap https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html

Comment: @SyrtisMajor: well, actually it has always been accepted, even in the builtin `file` object. That message comes from a Python that did not have `bytearray`s as we have today.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini But it disappear in Python 3.5. The object created by `open` has no `readinto` method.

Comment: @SyrtisMajor: in Python 3, `open()` opens file in text mode by default. `readinto()` is a feature of binary files. Try `open(..., 'rb')`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Yes, you're right. I do feel that in Python 3 things are more self-consistent and better organized. So it implies that `readinto` has indeed been accepted, even in the builtin file object.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini @PadraicCunningham: I think you may post your argument as an answer. Both are good and helpful ;)  And I shall draw back mine as it seems to be safe to use `open` directly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham BTW, is it possible to map two or more file into one `mmap` object?  Then we needn't to read data explicitly. As far as I see, the answer is no.

Comment: @SyrtisMajor, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There are several files. I want to read a part(slice) of each file into one array. This array is very big (several GB or more). In some case, only a small (but not continuous) fraction of the array would be accessed. These files are numerical simulation results.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `io.FileIO` in python standard library instead of the build-in function `open` or `file`, if you are not sure with `file.readinto`.

Here's the docstring:

```
#io.FileIO.readinto?
Type:        method_descriptor
String form: <method 'readinto' of '_io.FileIO' objects>
Docstring:   readinto() -> Same as RawIOBase.readinto().
```

The document of `io.RawIOBase.readinto` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readinto).

> class io.RawIOBase
>
> ...
>
> readinto(b)
>
> Read up to len(b) bytes into bytearray b and return the number of bytes read. If the object is in non-blocking mode and no bytes are available, None is returned.

It's available in both Python 2 and 3.